# Do our blood vessels exude chemicals?

Tags: hematology, histology

I watched a youtube video explaining how mosquitoes detect our blood vessels through "*chemicals that our blood vessels exude naturally*"

I was wondering if it's true that our blood vessels exude any chemicals, and which chemicals are they.

[Link to the video in case anyone is interested https://youtu.be/rD8SmacBUcU]

Comment: If so, it's probably more accurate to say that mosquitoes have developed a way to sense chemicals our blood vessels exude, not that our blood vessels exude chemicals mosquitos can sense. It's a subtle difference, I'll agree, but kind of important.

Comment: @WillihamTotland Thanks, i edited out the mosquitoes part in the title, since my interest is really whether or not our blood vessels do exude any chemicals.